# Generate GraphQL schema from Ballerina GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, ballerina

Currently, I am trying out Ballerina support for GraphQL.

Is it possible for me to get the generated GraphQL schema using Ballerina?

Answer (score 2):

The Ballerina GraphQL tool supports generating the GraphQL schema for a given Ballerina GraphQL service and writing it to a file using the GraphQL schema definition language (SDL). You will be able to export the generated schema file to the given location.

If your Ballerina file has multiple GraphQL services, you can use this command to generate schemas for all of them:

`$ bal graphql -i <ballerina-service-file-path> -o <output-location>`

To generate a schema for a specific service in a Ballerina file with multiple services, use this command:

`$ bal graphql -i <ballerina-service-file-path> -o <output-location> -s <service-base-path>`

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL schema can be generated using `bal graphql` command. Here we have to specify the GraphQL configuration file path or ballerina GraphQL service file path as input(-i) and the location to generate the schema as output(-o).

Please run the command `bal graphql` for more details.